# Mix opensource software and release under GPL3, MIT, BSD licenses

Tags: open-source, licensing

i am writing a javascript library and i am thinking to give it under triple licensed GPL3, MIT, BSD.

Also i found an Apache 2.0 open source project which i would like to include it in my project.

According to http://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html 
Apache 2 software can be included in GPLv3 projects, so my project's GPL3 version is compatible.

Can i include Apache 2.0 code in MIT and BSD project, so the final project can be compatible with the triple license GPL3, MIT, BSD?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. You need to consult an intellectual property lawyer in the country where you live or claim copyright, not ask the Internet.

Comment: i think we can make our lifes easier if we share information about open source licenses. This subject about how to mix code from major licenses it is something that many people should come across and may be known. The lawyer advice is something that i do if i cant find the info i want with other ways.

Comment: Either MIT or BSD would be compatible with GPL, MIT, BSD or Apache licensed projects.  A triple license would be possible but a single liberal license would make your library usable by pretty much any project.  The only reason to choose GPL would be if you feel strongly about compelling people to feed all improvements back to you.

Comment: @simonc very nice comment. Indeed GPL has this feature. But at last i changed my license to Apache2.0 / GPL3. In this way i can include code from other projects of Apache2.0, MIT, GPL licenses. As i see Apache2.0 license accepts code from the most major licenses but this is one way compatibility. However, GPLv3 software cannot be included in Apache projects. The licenses are incompatible in one direction only. So to benefit from both cases i decided to have dual license Apache2.0 for anyone who want to use it permissive license and GPL3 for the community, so as you say to get the feed back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5):

i found this site
http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/floss-license-slide.html

which explains realy simple which code can be used in which projects.

As i see, i can include MIT, BSD and Apache2.0 code and produce my GPL3 project.
But i cannot use Apache2.0 code to produce MIT or BSD projects.

The compatibility is only one way.
So if i want to make my project multilicensed and permissive compatible i have to publish it under Apache2.0/GPL3 licenses.

Comment: Can I get some clarity on your "one way"?
As an author (copyright holder), couldn't you release under 3: MIT, BSD, Apache2 - triple license - and eliminate the conflict?

Comment: I don't understand why people come up with lawyers. This is a very common problem. Very helpful! Thank you for sharing the link!